# ng-options as directive parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I have the same question asked on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42146289/ng-options-in-a-custom-directive-in-angular-1-x), sadly, no one has answered, so, here it goes again

I'm trying to create a select directive, where I can send the ng-options as a parameter.

This is my directive

```
app.directive('dropDown', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function (element, attrs) {
            return '<div class="col-sm-{{labelCol}} control-label">' +
                        '<label>{{label}}:</label>' +
                    '<div>' +
                    '<div clas="col-sm-{{controlCol}}">' +
                        '<label style="cursor:pointer" ng-show="!edit && forEdit" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="edit = true;">{{ngModel}}</label>' +
                        '<i ng-show="!edit && forEdit && !disabled" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="cursor:pointer" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="edit = true;"></i>' +
                        '<select name="{{name}}" ng-change="ngChange" ng-blur="edit = false" ng-show="edit || !forEdit" class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel" ng-required="required" ng-options={{options}}/>' +
                    '</div>'
        },
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            ngChange: '&',
            label: '@',
            labelCol: '@',
            controlCol: '@',
            type: '@',
            name: '@',
            disabled: '=',
            required: '=',
            forEdit: "=",
            options: "@"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { },
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            if (!attrs.labelCol) attrs.labelCol = '4';
            if (!attrs.controlCol) attrs.controlCol = '8';
            if (!attrs.required) attrs.required = false;
            if (!attrs.disabled) attrs.disabled = false;
            if (!attrs.forEdit) attrs.forEdit = false;
            attrs.edit = !attrs.forEdit;
        }

    }
})
```

And this is a implementation of the directive

```
<div class="row">
    <drop-down ng-model="site" for-edit="true" label="Site Test" options="x.SITE_CODE as x.SITE_NAME for x in sites"></drop-down>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <drop-down ng-model="site1" for-edit="true" label="Site Test" options="x for x in sites1"></drop-down>
</div>
```

And I'm getting the same response

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'in' is an unexpected token
>   at column 3 of the expression [x in sites1] starting at [in sites1].
>
> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'as' is an unexpected token
>   at column 13 of the expression [x.SITE_CODE as x.SITE_NAME for x in
>   sites] starting at [as x.SITE_NAME for x in sites].

Any idea how to achieve my desired result?

Edit1:

If it help, here's the arrays that should be filling the selects

```
$scope.sites = JSON.parse("[{\"SITE_CODE\":\"1\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"SITE1\",},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"2\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"SITE2\"},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"3\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"SITE3\"},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"4\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"SITE4\"}]");
$scope.sites1 = ["SITE1", "SITE2", "SITE3", "SITE4"];
```

Edit 2:

Added the error for the more complex ng-options sentence

Edit 3:

So, I just realized that, I'm setting the ngOptions as a 2 way databinding field on the scope, as, it's not necesary, so I changed it from `=` to `@` and now, I'm getting another error message

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'select', required by directive 'ngOptions', can't be found!

Which, it's unreasonable, as I'm indeed setting the ngOptions, and I can verify it on the compile

Edit 4:

So, after some testing, I'm finally getting my controls rendered, but sadly, withouth values

The selects are clearly on the controller div

```
<div class="content" ng-controller="testController">   
    <div class="row">
        <drop-down ng-model="site" for-edit="true" label="Site Test" options="x for x in sites"></drop-down>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <drop-down ng-model="site" label="Site Test" options="x for x in sites"></drop-down>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <drop-down ng-model="site1" for-edit="true" label="Site Test" options="x for x in sites1"></drop-down>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller indeed has this collections

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sites = JSON.parse("[{\"SITE_CODE\":\"1\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"SITE1\",},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"2\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"SITE2\"},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"3\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"SITE3\"},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"4\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"SITE4\"}]");
    $scope.sites1 = ["SITE1", "SITE2", "SITE3", "SITE4"];
}]);
```

But my rendered controls comes without any values
[image]

This is the rendered html for one of the controls

```
<div ng-model="site" label="Site Test" options="x for x in sites" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-valid">
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label"><label class="ng-binding">Site Test:</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <label style="cursor:pointer" ng-show="!edit &amp;&amp; forEdit" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="edit = true;" class="ng-binding ng-hide"></label>
        <i ng-show="!edit &amp;&amp; forEdit &amp;&amp; !disabled" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o ng-hide" style="cursor:pointer" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="edit = true;"></i>
        <select name="" ng-change="ngChange" ng-blur="edit = false" ng-show="edit || !forEdit" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-model="ngModel" ng-required="required" ng-options="x for x in sites">
            <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
        </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

At least now I'm getting my controls rendered, now, on to show some values on them

Comment: Have you misspelled it here `forEdit && !dsiabled` rather than `disabled`

Comment: @muasif80 thanks, fixed the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after much testing, I finally am able to achieve my desired result.

I'll leave the directive here to whoever might want to use it, as it allows to

1. Set a desired options string
2. Set a property to show in case we store the complete object in the model
3. Disabled status, that will only show the model value
4. Inline edit of the value

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.sites = JSON.parse("[{\"SITE_CODE\":\"1\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"TEST 1\"},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"2\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"TEST 2\"},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"3\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"TEST 3\"},{\"SITE_CODE\":\"4\",\"SITE_NAME\":\"TEST 4\"}]");
  $scope.sites1 = ["TEST 1", "TEST 2", "TEST 3"];

}]);

app.directive('dropDown', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngOptions',
    template: function(element, attrs) {
      return '<div>' +
        '<div class="col-sm-{{labelCol}} control-label">' +
        '<label>{{label}}:</label>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-sm-{{controlCol}}">' +
        '<label ng-show="!edit && forEdit">{{ngModel[textValue] !== undefined ? ngModel[textValue] : ngModel}}</label> ' +
        '<span ng-show="!edit && forEdit && !disabled" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="cursor:pointer" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="edit = true;">click here for edit</span>' +
        '<select name="{{name}}" ng-change="ngChange" ng-blur="edit = false" ng-show="edit || !forEdit" class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel" ng-required="required" ng-options="{{options}}"/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    },
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      ngChange: '&',
      label: '@',
      labelCol: '@',
      controlCol: '@',
      type: '@',
      name: '@',
      disabled: '=',
      required: '=',
      forEdit: "=",
      options: "@",
      items: "=",
      textValue: "@"
    },
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      if (!attrs.labelCol) attrs.labelCol = '4';
      if (!attrs.controlCol) attrs.controlCol = '8';
      if (!attrs.required) attrs.required = false;
      if (!attrs.disabled) attrs.disabled = false;
      if (!attrs.forEdit) attrs.forEdit = false;
      if (attrs.disabled)
        attrs.forEdit = "true";
      attrs.edit = !attrs.forEdit;
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    },

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="" ng-controller="testController">
    <div class="row">
      <drop-down ng-model="site" for-edit="true" label="Site Test Inline" text-value="SITE_NAME" options="x.SITE_NAME for x in items" items="sites"></drop-down>
      <drop-down ng-model="site1" for-edit="false" label="Site Test Select" options="x for x in items" items="sites1"></drop-down>
      <drop-down ng-model="site1" disabled="true" label="Site Test Disabled" options="x for x in items" items="sites1"></drop-down>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `ng-options="x in sites1"` is incorrect.

In it's most simplest form it should be **label** for **value** in **array**:

```
ng-options="x for x in sites1"
```

Also check out the [angular docs for ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to see all of the permitted argument forms.

Comment: Sorry, but it's definitely valid, as I'm using **select** as **label** for **value** in **array** and this is a sentence I had used on several other selects I have in my project. As you can see, I have 2 drop-down, one with this sentence, and another with a simpler one, `x in sites1` that also gives a similar error message on the console

Comment: @CJLopez Sure, the first one `ng-options="x.SITE_CODE as x.SITE_NAME for x in sites"` (valid syntax) is fine, it's the second one with the `ng-options="x in sites1"` (invalid syntax) that raises the error

Comment: No, I'm also getting error for that one as well >Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'as' is an unexpected token at column 13 of the expression [x.SITE_CODE as x.SITE_NAME for x in sites] starting at [as x.SITE_NAME for x in sites].